# CEX order book market update

Tags: api, bitcoin, trading

I am trying to use cex.io API to construct a live order book, but I am struggling understanding the message from the API.

I am subscribing with the following JSON:

```
{
  "e":    "order-book-subscribe",
  "data": {
            "pair":      [
                          "BTC",
                          "USD"
                          ],
            "subscribe": false,
            "depth":    -1
            },
  "oid": "1435927928274_3_order-book-subscribe"
  }
```

The first message is a snapshot of the order book, this one its ok.

But next, the messages are "just" updates, same as this one :

```
{ 
  'e':    'md_update',
  'data': { 
           'id':    92276361,
           'pair': 'BTC:USD',
           'time':  1505337293621,
           'bids':  [],
           'asks':  [
                      [4078.1692, 0.0]
                      ]
           }
  }
```

How do I update the snapshot first received with the updates lines ?

How do I know, if some of the lines if there was match in the book ?

And also if I subscribe with `depth = 1`, would the updates only be for best bid / best ask ?

Comment: I'm interested in similar. How do I know if the update is in addition, or subtraction to the initial snapshot? Not well documented.

Comment: @JAC2703 See my answer. It is neither addition nor substraction. It is the new amount of the order.

Answer (score 3):

You simply match the updates with the current state of your internal orderbook. The API sends you the *changes* which are made to the orderbook on server side.

Example:

The update message is:

```
{ 
  'e':    'md_update',
  'data': { 
    'id':    92276361,
    'pair': 'BTC:USD',
    'time':  1505337293621,
    'bids':  [],
    'asks':  [
               [4070, 0.0],
               [4080, 1]
             ]
  }
}
```

We see the ask with *4070* price has now an remaining amount of *0*. So delete that entry from your orderbook.

Ask *4080* now has an remaining amount of *1*. You check if there is already an ask with price *4080* in your orderbook. If so, update the amount to *1*. If there is no ask with *4080* in your orderbook, add an entry with price *4080* and amount *1* to your orderbook.